# jQuery left and right button scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now and can't seem to make any headway. I am trying to do a simple left and right scroll using images as the scrollers but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/7GrTM/1/

HTML

```
<div class="outerwrapper">
   <div class="innerwrapper">
     <div class="productsbox">
          <img class="box_image" src="images/productsbox1.png" style="width:222px" alt="this"/>
     </div>
     <div class="spacer"></div>
     <div class='productsbox'>  
          <img class='box_image' src="images/productsbox2.png" style='width:222px' alt="this"/>
     </div>
     <div class="spacer"></div>
     <div class='productsbox'>  
          <img class='box_image' src="images/productsbox3.png" style='width:222px' alt="this"/>                      
     </div>
     <div class="spacer"></div>
     <div class='productsbox'>  
          <img class='box_image' src="images/productsbox4.png" style='width:221px' alt="this"/>  
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class='productsbox'>  
         <img class='box_image' src="images/productsbox5.png" style='width:221px' alt="this"/>  
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class='productsbox'>  
         <img class='box_image' src="images/productsbox6.png" style='width:221px' alt="this"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="productspace">
        <img src="images/arrowleft.png" id="#left" alt="left"/>
        <img src="images/arrowright.png" id="#right" style="padding-left: 10px;" alt="right"/>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $("#outerwrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '422' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

CSS

```
.spacer {
    width: 20px;
    height: 319px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.outerwrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 323px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innerwrapper {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 322px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help will be appreciative.

Comment: What isn't working? Displaying the pictures? Actually getting the buttons to scroll? Please specify

Comment: Images display fine, scrolling doesn't work

Comment: You're setting the buttons ID's wrong. replace `id="#right1"` and `id="#left1"` with `id="right"` and `id="left"`

Comment: Your pictures does not show up in the jsfiddle, but I also notice that the IDs are actually `left1` and `right1`, not `left` and `right`. Can this be the reason?

Comment: yeah i fixed that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, it only scrolls right if you scroll left first. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/cGNdm/

Comment: I got it Joe thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs are wrong, you have named them `#left` and `#right`, not simply `left` and `right`. In your JSfiddle you have managed to set this as the id: `#left1` and `#right1`.

Solution: Change the ID's to say `left` and `right`, so you will have:

```
<div class="productspace">
    <img src="images/arrowleft.png" id="left" alt="left"/>
    <img src="images/arrowright.png" id="right" style="padding-left: 10px;" alt="right"/>
</div>
```

You are also trying to access your div with class `outerwrapper` as a `id`, not as a `class`. Either change outerwrapper to be an ID so `<div id="outerwrapper">` or change the jquery to look for the class: `$(".outerwrapper")` (the prior solution is in my mind superior, so change div id).

Comment: @Keith It's the right solution but you're probably expecting some magical scrolling which won't work in your current HTML and JS.

Comment: that is why I posted all of my script on the board here to see what exactly is wrong with the script

Comment: i missed that last part you said, switched the id to a class and it worked. I feel dumb...

Comment: I was struggeling to get this to work in jsfiddle. I think there are some jsfiles that I was not able to import there or something. Hopefully it worked out for you.